# In Pollard p-1 how is the bound B chosen?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, prime-factorization

Does [Pollard's p-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm) method always produce an answer (given sufficient time and assuming input is composite)? If yes, what is the point of having the bound $B$, why not just keep increasing $a$? If no, how is $B$ reasonably guessed?

Is there a limit to how large $B$ should be? For example if the input is prime then checking up $B=\sqrt{\text{input}}$ would prove there's no factors, is that correct?

Comment: We do not know which $B$ is sufficient. We can only hope to find a factor with some given bound $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p-1-method works , if there is a prime factor $\ p\ $ of $\ N\ $ , such that $\ p-1\ $ splits into prime factors smaller than the chosen bound $\ B\ $. Whether a given bound $\ B\ $ will work, cannot be predicted.

Of course, increasing $\ B\ $ would eventually find a non-trivial factor, but at some point, this method would be not more efficient (perhaps even less efficient) then trial division.

If we are lucky, we can find large factors that could not be found with trial division in reasonable time.

The p-1-method rarely works , if there is no prime factor with , lets say , $\ 25\ $ digits or less. In this case, the better ECM (elliptic curve method) is usually used.

Comment: "increasing  B  would eventually find a non-trivial factor" this is assuming the input is composite. At what point can it be concluded that the input is prime? For example it doesn't make sense to set B greater than the square root of the input, right?

Comment: @northerner If the number is not too large , you should check the number for primality before running p-1-method anyway. There are efficient tests for checking whether a number is prime. Miller Rabin is a good start.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is, why have does the algorithm have a bound at all? Since as you said a factor will always be found.

Comment: The purpose to set a bound is just to ensure a reasonable running time.